# Stack TD's from different TR's under each under

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-tables

Let's say we want to make the following table responsive.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Dog Image</td>
    <td>Cat Image</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Dog Text</td>
    <td>Cat Text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What is the best solution? What I want (done using CSS):

```
Dog Image
Dog Text

Cat Image
Cat Text
```

Setting a display block on the td's won't be the solution, I wouldn't want the two images under each other. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Judging by the expected content and display, I think it is not correct to use `table`s. Can you not modify the HTML? Is that a restriction?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I am allowed to add some classes or ID's, but I won't be able to replace the table with some divs and style those accordingly. The website is old, so the content area's are created using tables.

Comment: The site is old, you can't change (at least sensibly) its markup, but you are demanded to make it responsive ? Sounds legit...

Comment: Yup, thats about it. I'm getting paid to make it responsive, even though the site is old. I won't be able to edit all the tables, but I can add a class using the layout they use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question seems very broad, because it is not clear which kind of markup you do really have, which rules can be assumed to be definitive etc...

But IF you really have an HTML table with an alternated sequence of images and texts, in the form of "row of images, row of texts, row of images, row of texts", then there is a problem with the content.

It's been used a tabular markup to represent non-tabular data, and the data itself has been splitted to adhere to visual needs, instead that to respect its logic structure.

Since you said you don't want to change the table markup, but also since you will most likely need to change something, then I suggest you to to do with the HTML5 way, that for a work like this is the usage of [the `<figure>` and `<figcaption>` elements](http://html5doctor.com/the-figure-figcaption-elements/).

With the help of Javascript, try automating the following changes to the source code:

- surround all the images with a `<figure>` element
- move all the texts to the previously created `<figure>` element, and enclose them in a `<figcaption>` tag.
- delete the row that used to contain the texts.

Then apply `display: inline-block;` to the `td`, and you will get the following result.

**Run the demo <kbd>Full page</kbd> and resize the window to see the `<td>`s becoming fluid.**

```css
figure {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
td {  
  vertical-align: top;  
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <figure>
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1285.jpg" alt="Dog">
        <figcaption>“A dog is the only thing on earth that loves <br>you 
                     more than he loves himself.”
          <br>
          <a href="http://www.goodreads.com/author/show/1865038.Josh_Billings">
            Josh Billings</a>
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </td>
    <td>
      <figure>
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FW9qs.jpg" alt="Cat">
        <figcaption>“What greater gift than the love of a cat.”
          <br>
          <a href="http://www.goodreads.com/author/show/239579.Charles_Dickens">
            Charles Dickens</a>
        </figcaption>
      </figure>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I know it's not the easy answer you're looking for, but given the peculiarity of your problem, I don't think you'll get it here (assuming that it exists).